# center of invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

find the center of the group of invertible 2 x 2 matrices with real entries.

Attempt: By definition, the center of a group Z(G), is where all the elements are commutative.
If G = { invertible 2 x 2 matrices}, then doing several multiplications of matrices,
Z(G) is equal to the 2 x 2 matrix where the main diagonal is k, and the rest of the entries are zero, where k is not equal to 0, and k is an element from the real numbers.

Can anyone please help me? I don't know if there are others. I have tries to do several multiplications to see which 2 matrices commute.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the center of the set of all 2x2 matrices?

Comment: The only center for the 2x2 matrices that I have found is my attempt. I don't know if this might be the only one.

Comment: @mookid Is the set of all $2 \times 2$ matrices a group? What does the center mean in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**General proof for the $n\times n$ case:**

Let $A\in Z(g)$,  $1\le i,j\le n$. Consider the elementary matrix $E_{ij}$ which only non 0 entry is on $(i,j)$.

Then $I + E_{ij}$ is invertible, so$$
A(I + E_{ij}) = (I + E_{ij})A \implies AE_{ij} = E_{ij}A
$$

Now, if you know the center of all $2\times 2$ matrices you know that 
$A$ has the form $xI$.

Otherwise, let us prove it:

$$A=\sum A_{kl}E_{kl}\\
AE_{ij} = E_{ij}A\iff \sum A_{kl}E_{kl}E_{ij} = \sum A_{kl}E_{ij} E_{kl}\\
\iff \sum A_{ki}E_{kj} = \sum A_{kl}E_{il}
$$
This gives looking at LHS:$$k\neq i\implies A_{ki}=0\\
k=i\implies A_{ii} = A_{kk}
$$that is, $A =A_{11}I$.

Now it remains to check that it is in the center.